# Mesh inverts its normals along a curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, path

I have added a mesh to follow a curve modifier. As seen in the screenshot, the normals are correct when starting to follow the curve, and when it exits the curve, the normals are flipped. What is causing this?

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here's the file:

https://pasteall.org/blend/d26b034e0c1248b8bb63ee970ee10fc9